# After changing to developer mode, website crashes

Tags: magento2, php, attributes, index

[image]magento 2.1.7
php 70

After changing magento to dev mode, website is crashing and getting php error
and can't understand what is that error about.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Just remove var folder content and check again.

Comment: Remove var folder files and give proper permission to that var folder and try.
Still you are facing this issue then try to disable all you third party module and run setup upgrade command and check.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the production command

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

and try again